# How to acquire information from form in javascript?

Tags: html, forms

Hey guys i was wondering how to acquire information from form in javascript and i found the method with object forms, but i doesnt want to work(returns undefined), because object is undefined. Do you know what i am doing wrong in that, could you attach some explanations? I know what it is possible to do it by getElement function,but i would like to understand why this solution doesn't work. 
Regards!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function cos(sth){
var par = document.getElementById("para1");
 par.style.color = 'blue';
 par.style.fontSize="30px";
 par.style.fontFamily="Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
}

function getFormValue(){
  document.write(5+6);
  var doc = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  // OR
  var doc = document.forms[0].elements["name"];
  document.write(doc);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id ="para1">JavaScript Exercises - w3resource</p>
<div>
<button onclick="cos();">Style</button>
</div>

<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <button onclick="getFormValue()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> document.write(5+6);
> var doc = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
> ```

Since the page has loaded, the document is in a closed state.

Calling `document.write` implicitly calls `document.open` which creates a new document.

You then write `11` to this document.

Next you try to get the form element. It doesn't exist in this new document.

Then you try to get the email field from it. Since you don't have a form, you get an error.

---

If you fix that:

> ```
> var doc = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
> // OR
> var doc = document.forms[0].elements["name"];
> document.write(doc);
> ```

You read the value of the email field and assign it to `doc`.

Then you overwrite it with `elements["name"]`.

There is no form control called `name`, so you get `undefined`.

---

```
var doc = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
document.write(doc);
```

… works fine. You just need to remove the junk you put around it to break it.

Comment: Thanks man, helped a lot! I didn't now that this may have such a enormous impact, thanks for explanation!